# HTML5: currentTime property

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I'm having a problem using currentTime in audio html5. It gives me an error in console

```
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
 or is no longer, usable
```

And a warning:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. 
Load of media resource http://s3.amazonaws.com/audiojs/02-juicy-r.mp3 failed.
```

But when I get rid of this line of codes I don't get any console error and warning.

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById('mediaElementID');
    mediaElement.currentTime = 29;
});
```

And I'm currently using the [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/). I've run through different modification in my code but still its not working. 
Here is my javascript code:

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
   audiojs.createAll();
   $(".play").click(function(){
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
    myAudio.currentTime = 29;
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when the load of mp3 file is failed. For example it fails in Firefox because it doesn't support mp3. And it seems to work in Chrome. Try to put different file formats for different browsers.

Comment: are you sure that mp3 file is loaded fine, and you don't get a warning like `HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource failed`

Comment: I don't get any console error and warning when I get rid of 
<pre>$(".play").click(function(){
            var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
            myAudio.currentTime = 29;
        });</pre>
But when I added it up I get both the error and the warning <pre>HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource failed</pre>
I don't know what is the problem, but I will try your suggestion. Thanks.:-)

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox convert your mp3 to ogg and use ogg. For Chrome mp3 works fine but it also works with ogg so if you convert to ogg you don't have to worry which browser needs what.